# Memory issue when using replace segue for iPad

Tags: ipad, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

When I use replace detailView segue app crashes.

I'm replacing a bunch of view controllers, (1st is navigation controller, then tabBar controller with view controllers). tabBar Controller is a delegate of splitViewController.

Error message is:

```
-[TabBarController splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:]: 
message sent to deallocated instance 0x9b7d180
```

Upd.: TabBarController code

```
//  TabBarController.m
#import "TabBarController.h"

@implementation TabBarController
@synthesize masterPopoverController = _masterPopoverController;
#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)awakeFromNib  // always try to be the split view's delegate
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = self;
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.delegate = self;
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = nil;
    self.delegate = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Split view

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
//    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
//    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
//    self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
//    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
//    self.masterPopoverController = nil;
}
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return NO;
}
@end
```

Comment: Very hard to debug memory issues without any code, but the message would seem to indicate that your TabBarController is registered (and called) as a delegate even after being released.

Comment: Too much code, I just had no idea what should be wrong. 
I'll update post with tabBar controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I assigned delegate of UISplitViewController to detailView.
Restarting detailView cause memory problems. 
After I made AppDelegate also the delegate of UISplitViewController problem was solved.